# Issue with Remove Deployment in Myeclipse

Tags: myeclipse

I am trying to remove deployment from the Myeclipse blue edition. I have added the IBM Websphere 6.1 application into the server. Created the AppServer1 profile and then i deployed project there. Now when I want to remove the project from there and when I do so, It says 
"An internal error occurred during: "Remove Deployment".
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException"

I have deleted the C:\Data\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\temp and C:\Data\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\wstemp folder, but that also did not help me.

Please help in same regard.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Check that the application is still deployed by using the WebSphere admin console. If it is, try uninstalling the application from the admin console. Then delete it from the installedApps folder in the profile (if it hasn't gone). Now when you try to remove the deployment in MyEclipse Blue, I think it will give you an error to say it isn't installed on the server but it should remove the record of the deployment from the server connector.

If you still have problems, I suggest you post to the MyEclipse forums at http://www.myeclipseide.com/forums